# How to create button according to database query in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have large list of categorize items for my small program.

Let's assume that I have a category named **Candy** and there are **more than 100 items** in the category Candy.

Here I query it by,

```
OleDbConnection dbConnect = new OleDBConnection("....");
dbConnect.Open();
string query = "SELECT ID, item FROM Items WHERE category == 'Candy'"; 
OleDBCommand executeCommand= new OleDBCommand(query, dbConnect);
OleDBDataReader reader = executeCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

The result might be many rows, where each row will have property of a button. A new button will be generated.

```
while(reader.Read()) {
// create multiple buttons for each row here..
}
```

Now the problem is, i want to show it in a WrapPanel with limited height and width.
Say that I can show only 10 buttons in the WrapPanel. However the buttons created are more than 50.

What is the best way to sort out this problem. I was thinking if I can modify query for 10 rows and create 10 buttons and another button with **NEXT** arrow will fetch another 10 buttons.

I am too much confused here. Please help me with the better solution.

Comment: Why not use a a ComboBox or a ListBox, it looks like it suits your needs better than a miriad of buttons...

Comment: @SvenG: I wanted this interface touch screen friendly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If number of items doesn't get to the thousands, I think you'll be better off (much less code, much simpler code) if you let WPF managing the view for you. How do plan users to browse through the buttons? Is it a scroll bar?

Also, looking at your sample code, it appears you intend to Create buttons on the fly within the 'while' loop. Again, while this is possible way, this is not the "textbook" solution or the simple solution for creating multiple items based on a collection. The suitable paradigm is using a Data Binding to an array of items.

Here is an example:

Within your XAML file, define a <ItemsControl>. Give it a name (say ButtonsPanel) so you can reference it from the code behind. In the code behind prepare an array (or List, or anything derived from IEnumerable) with all the items you want to present, and set the ItemsSource of your element to this list.

ItemsControl is a very generic Items Control. You can define the ItemsPanel (i.e. the panel the contains all the items) as well as template for all the buttons.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ButtonsPanel" Height="80" Width="50">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>        
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>       
</ItemsControl>
```

EDIT (following comment from user995387): 
With Prev/Next buttons (a.k.a. paging) data binding is also the preferred paradigm. Within the data context of your control (or the code behind) have a ObservableCollection with the 10 items that you want to present. Uppon a click on the 'Next' button, either replace the entire collection, or the 10 items within the collection (Clear and 10 Adds), or the content of the items within the collection (in which case, the item has to fire INotifyPropertyChanged event) - whichever makes more sense to you. Choose the last option only if creating 10 new buttons (as opposed to update the content of each button) has performance penalty.

Comment: " A button with NEXT arrow will fetch another 10 buttons."  
Your advice was valuable.

Comment: In case if I prefer Scrollbar how can I add to it?

Comment: @user995387 - if you want to have a scrollbar, you can embed the wrap panel within a ScrollViewer element with VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto". However, you'll be better off ignoring the WrapPanel all together and just use a List (which has a built-in scroll bar).

Comment: The buttons are appropriate for touchscreen interface.